# Можно ли сказать "более медленный"?

Tags: степени-прилагательных

Можно ли, согласно нормам русского языка, сказать: "Более медленный" ?

Comment: А вы как считаете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вполне корректно:Более медленный темп, более медленный шар в боулинге, более медленный процесс

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/279256/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9